# Can we use the verb "watch" without any object?

Tags: verb-usage

I am sharing a link to a video on my WhatsApp and I'm not sure if the caption I'm writing is correct.

> Watch with the subtitles on.

Do I need to say "watch it with..."?

Or "watch the video with..."

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with omitting the direct object of a transitive verb, if the listener will make the right assumption about what is missing.  An obvious case where you should not assume is when the verb is commonly intransitive (cf "He was the CEO of the company and he ran with an iron fist.")

P.S. You can also assume that the listener knows which subtitles to use, so the definite article is superfluous (especially in a sign or caption) so you can say "watch with subtitles on".

Comment: Thanks very much. Omitting the "the" also makes sense. Much appreciated.